# Preg_replace with PHP and MySQL, allowing dashes and brackets

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I have a website where people can add content and when they type in titles, all characters are filtered when parsing to MySQL with PHP, only allowing members to write text and numbers. But I want to allow dashes (`-`) and brackets/parenthesis (`()`). Currently, I have:

```
$video_title = preg_replace('#[^A-za-z0-9 ?!.,]#i', '', $_POST['video_title']);
```

What shall I add or remove to the preg_replace function to allow these characters?

Comment: Add the characters to your class by escaping them with a slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `\( \) \-` to the expression

```
[^a-z0-9 ?!.,()-]
```

Since it just got erased, you only the the `a-z` once if it is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not really an answer, but it didn't fit well in the comment box.*

Note that `A-z` may not do what you expect in a regexp character class: it matches all characters whose ASCII code lies between those of `A` and `z`, which includes all upper- and lowercase letters, but also a bunch of punctuation characters:

```php
echo join("", preg_grep("/[A-z]/", array_map("chr", range(0, 255)))) . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```